# Catalog Price Rule to the minute

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, catalog-price-rules, datetime

I have set up a Catalog Price Rule for all products and I can set a start and end date but what about the time?

Is there a way that I can add the time to the end date?

Comment: mike,did not get ur point .. `I can set a start and end date but what about the time?`

Comment: Say if I wanted to end the rule after 1 hour or at 2 PM the following day.